# Concatenate stored procedure parameters into SQL Server script

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to concatenate stored procedure parameters with this script which I use to create login and password and give it sysadmin permission here is my script

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[crearte_user] 
    @login_name NVARCHAR(200),
    @pass NVARCHAR(200)
AS
    EXEC ('create login'+@login_name+'WITH password='''+@pass+''',check_policy=OFF,check_expiration=OFF')
    EXEC ('sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame ='@pass, @rolename = N'sysadmin')
```

The compiler throws this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure crearte_user, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near '@pass'.

Comment: You have a comma after the @pass in the second exec, which is not valid syntax. You have more issues than just that one though (no spaces after create login means you are going to concatenate the word login and the login_name and WITH like `create login@login_nameWITH password`

Comment: I don't see why you need dynamic SQL with the second call at all.  You can just do `EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = @login_name, @rolename = N'sysadmin'`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just have a few quotes missing, you've also put `@pass` as the `@loginname`, is that intentional?

I'm assuming you're looking for (I've switched `@pass` for `@login_name`):

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[crearte_user] @login_name nvarchar(200),@pass nvarchar(200)
as
exec('create login ' + @login_name + ' WITH password = ''' + @pass + ''', check_policy=OFF, check_expiration=OFF')
exec('sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = ''' + @login_name + ''', @rolename = N''sysadmin''')
```

Also note `''sysadmin''`, you need to put `'` twice when it's inside of a string.